# @TestPropertySource and @Value not loading properties in tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing, spring-boot-test

I have a test class with the following code:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
class AccessTokenServiceTest {
  @Mock private AccessTokenBlacklistRepository accessTokenBlacklistRepository;
  @Mock private UserBlacklistRepository userBlacklistRepository;
  @Mock private MessageService messageService;
  @InjectMocks private AccessTokenServiceImpl accessTokenService;

  // tests...
}
```

in my application-test.properties file, which is located at `src/test/resources` I have:

```
...
jwt.secret=secret
...
```

and finally, in my service, I'm getting value from properties file with:

```
@Value("${jwt.secret}")
private String secret;
```

secret is being populated when I'm running the app, everything is fine, but the problem is when I try to run my test. Whatever I tried, the secret is always null.

I even tried to set properties directly inside test class with:

```
@TestPropertySource(
    properties = {
      "jwt.secret=secret",
    })
```

but that also returned null for a secret.

Currently, I fixed this issue with the following code:

```
@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
  ReflectionTestUtils.setField(accessTokenService, "secret", "secret");
}
```

but I'm looking for a better approach.

I'm using spring boot 3.0.6

Answer (score -1):

You also need to extend with `SpringExtension` for your Spring Injections to work. Something like below should work in your case:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
class AccessTokenServiceTest {
  @Mock private AccessTokenBlacklistRepository accessTokenBlacklistRepository;
  @Mock private UserBlacklistRepository userBlacklistRepository;
  @Mock private MessageService messageService;
  @InjectMocks private AccessTokenServiceImpl accessTokenService;

  // tests...
}
```

You might not need `ReflectionTestUtils` in this case.

Comment: That did not resolve it. I even try to annotate it with `SpringBootTest`, just as a test, to see if loading the whole context would help, but the problem remains.